C# ASP.NET MVC project
I am a C# student.
There is a problem with my Razor view. I'm trying to setup the dropdown list, so that if I select an option and press "Rekening toevoegen"(add receipt), the page does a post and redirects to the same view, and the selected option is now the one being initially selected.
This is the IActionResult of my controller
        public IActionResult Rekeningen(string geselecteerdeTafel)
        {
            List<Rekening>? rekeningenVanTafel = _rekeningService.OpenstaandeRekeningPerTafel(geselecteerdeTafel);
            var tafels = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Tafels)).Cast<Tafels>().ToList();
            ViewBag.Tafels = tafels;
            ViewBag.geselecteerdeTafel = geselecteerdeTafel == null ? "Tafel1" : geselecteerdeTafel;

            return View("TafelOpenstaandeRekTonen", rekeningenVanTafel);
        }

and this is the post action
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult RekeningLaden(string tafel)
        {

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Rekeningen),tafel);
        }

This is the piece of the view in question
@model List<GastroLogic.Models.Entities.Rekening>?
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "TafelOpenstaandeRekeningenTonen";
}
<p>Geselecteerde Tafel: @ViewBag.geselecteerdeTafel</p>

<form asp-action="RekeningLaden" method="post">
    <select name="geselecteerdeOptie" class="form-control">
        @foreach (var tafel in ViewBag.Tafels)
        {
            <option value="@tafel" selected="@(tafel.ToString() == ViewBag.geselecteerdeTafel ? "selected" : "")">@tafel</option>
        }
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Rekening toevoegen" />
</form>

The problem is that selected="@(tafel.ToString() == ViewBag.geselecteerdeTafel ? "selected" : "")
doesn't work.
I also tried
\<option value="@tafel" @(tafel.ToString() == ViewBag.geselecteerdeTafel ? "selected" : "")\>@tafel\</option\> 

but then I get fault RZ1031 the tag helper 'option' must not have c# elements...
I tried disabling @addtaghelper in _ViewImports but then the links stop working sinds asp functions are disabled then
to clarify some dutch words:
"tafels" means tables. it's an enum with all the possible tables of a restaurant.
"tafel"is 1 table of the restaurant.
"geselecteerdeTafel" means selected table
       <option value="@tafel" @(tafel.ToString() == ViewBag.geselecteerdeTafel ? "selected" : "")>@tafel</option> resulted in the fault RZ1031 as explained above. 

Removing @addtaghelpers helped but then the links stopped working and asp actions are disabled

Let me know if I understand what you are trying. Basically, you are showing Selected Tafel: Tafel A, followed by a dropdown with the list of all Tafels (Tafel B, C, D...) When the user selected a different tafel, it should submit and refresh the page, showing now the name of the selected tafel. Is that right?

i think you have an issue with the quotes in your c# not being escaped. try change the option line to this: <option value="@tafel" @(tafel.ToString() == ViewBag.geselecteerdeTafel ? "selected" : "")>@tafel</option>

Firstly, I suggest you could modify your drop down to avoid using the ternary operator, using a razor friendly way like below:
<form asp-action="RekeningLaden" method="post">
    <select name="geselecteerdeOptie" class="form-control">
        @foreach (var tafel in ViewBag.Tafels)
        {
            if (tafel.ToString() == ViewBag.geselecteerdeTafel)
            {
                <option value="@tafel" selected>@tafel</option>
            }
            else
            {
                <option value="@tafel">@tafel</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Rekening toevoegen" />
</form>

Besides, you couldn't remove the tag helper, if you remove the tag helper, all the asp-action will not work.
